# What is the difference between container() and getContent() in Kineticjs?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

Having a Stage in Kineticjs:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container : 'container',
    width : 500,
    height : 500
});
```

**What is the difference between the following lines?**

```
var container = stage.container();
```

and

```
var content = stage.getContent();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You supply the container div...KineticJS adds the content div to host all its operations.**

The container is the html div element you created to hold all the sub-elements that KineticJS will create to "do-its-thing".

The content a child div that KineticJS creates inside your container element.

After KineticJS executes, the content div is the one with class="kineticjs-content".